# How to scrape data on following url in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, purrr, rselenium

I am scraping one website for practicing and I have used RVEST to scrape data about products from 250 pages.

I have used the code below which worked awesome and I downloaded the data I wanted. Now I want to add another column with the type of the product (lets say grocery, cosmetics, lifestyle etc) but this information is present once you click on particular product. And here is where I stuck to figure it out how to update the code to make him follow the link and scrape that data on the next page and assign it to correct product.

This is the website where i try to practice https://www.zlacnene.sk/akciovy-tovar/strana-2

```
url_base <- "https://www.zlacnene.sk/akciovy-tovar/strana-%d"

map_df(2:226, function(i) {

  # simple but effective progress indicator
  cat(".")

  pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))

  data.frame(wine=html_text(html_nodes(pg, "h2 a")),
             store=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".prodejnaName")),
             price=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".cena")),
            duration=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".platnostInfo dd")),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

}) -> groceries
```

**UPDATE** I have tried to use this code to navigate to another link but still far away from end result.

```
url <- "https://www.zlacnene.sk/akciovy-tovar/strana-2"

new <- list()

cast <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("h2 a") %>% html_text()

s <- html_session("https://www.zlacnene.sk/akciovy-tovar/strana-2")

for (i in cast[1:20]) {

  page <- s %>% follow_link(i) %>% read_html()

  new[[i]] <- page %>% html_nodes(".breadcrumbs a:nth-child(3)")

}
```

The expected end result should be that i will have another two columns with information about the product which are in the breadcrumbs with this css selector .home~ a+ a

Once you click on a product then on other site is in top left corner bredacrumps with the product classification.

Any help is welcomed and much thanks for understanding

Comment: I was searching for options to do it and i found specifically that there is a function jump_to() and follow_link(). Probably that is the way to go but am not sure how to structure the code. Here is the link to source : https://rdrr.io/cran/rvest/man/jump_to.html

Comment: You are expecting one or two more columns? You mention 2 more columns but then only explicitly refer to category of product (one column). The category being the result of first match (?) of .home~ a+ a  on any given product page e.g. `https://www.zlacnene.sk/akcia/giana-olej-1-l-3336128/`  > Potraviny

Comment: Yeah I figure it now that i have put one css selector and told 2 columns. The best is to have two sperate columns with two seperate css selectors. Thanks for question, my fault.

Comment: So the last two columns would be _Potraviny_  and _trvanlivé_ for example?  (and one css selector is fine if using html_nodes as just change index)

Comment: @QHarr Exactly! Thank you very much for your help. I was trying to use the example from Hadley with html_session, follow_link and back(), but still not made it.

Comment: Use `html_attr('href')` to extract the links to products and then extract required data.